# Tell Cocoa App to quit if incorrect login

Tags: cocoa, security

I want to quit my cocoa app if a user tries to enter an incorrect passcode or tries to cancel the login process.

Is it ok to use this:

```
[NSApp performSelector:@selector(terminate:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
```

or is there something else preferred?

Comment: You don't need to use `performSelector:...`. Just send `terminate:`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On a Macintosh, it's okay to self terminate as long as the user clearly understands why the app is quitting.

On an iOS device, it would be better to leave the user stuck at the login screen and throw up "wrong password" alerts.  Apple tends to frown on self-terminating apps on the iPhone.

Comment: Thanks Michael, that's the way I have the iOS version working (repeating warnings). As this is my first public desktop mac app, I wanted to be certain this is the best way to terminate in case of foul play.

Comment: Just saw your revised comment. Using the menu item Quit, does sound like a better way. Thanks again

Comment: The `terminate:` does a "clean" shutdown, it does basically the same as the "Quit" menu item (including calling the relevant delegate methods). There's no need to deal with nasty Apple Events just to quit an app.

Comment: hmm, I thought "`terminate`" took an app down immediately @omz. Would calling "`terminate`" on a dirty NSDocument window bring up the save dialog?

Comment: No, it's quite different from something like `exit(0)`. See [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSApplication/terminate:), it says explicitly that unsaved documents will be saved, `applicationShouldTerminate:` is called, etc.

Comment: Awwright. Rolling back my edit and thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @omz, I just tried "terminate", and it does quit the app immediately.. Maybe I should add an "Are you sure?" dialog.

Comment: Well, if there's nothing stopping it (e.g. unsaved documents that don't implement auto-save), it will of course terminate immediately. You could implement the delegate method `applicationShouldTerminate:` to show a confirmation dialog or cancel the termination depending on some other condition.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann: You're thinking of `SIGTERM`. `terminate:` is invoked by the Quit menu item. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSApplication/terminate: